# Display form elements side by side in CakePHP

Tags: css, cakephp

How do I display the form elements side by side instead of vertically? I tried display inline and `div=false` as per other peoples questions on this. Nothing works?

```
echo $this->Form->input('c', array(
 'label'=>' ',
 'type'=>'number',
 'div'=>false,
 'style' => 'width: 50px; height: 30px; display:inline-block;',
 'value'=>'0' 
));

echo $this->Form->input('d', array(
  'label'=>' ',
  'type'=>'number',
  'div'=>false,
  'style' => 'width: 50px; height: 30px; display:inline-block;',
  'value'=>'0' 
));
```

Comment: Styling is usually done with CSS: Give both form elements a name (`'div'=>'yourdivname'`) and then add formatting in your CSS file (`display: inline` or `float: left; width: 50%;` or `display: flex;` or whatever...); Another note: To disable the label please use `'label' => false` or also hide it via CSS (for accessibility it's better to keep the label)...

Comment: `display:inline` would be one way, but if you use bootstrap then they have inbuilt classes that you can implement to do this for you, in a tidy fashion

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default form building by cake, then all you have to do is add a CSS for input class. In this case you should not set div as false. Use the simple way, like

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('c'); ?>
```

And for the CSS

```
EX:
<style>
   .input{display:inline-block;}
   .input{width:auto}/* incase you have applied some styles related to width*/

</style>
```